# Acesso a objetos em PHP em outras páginas

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou começando a programar com orientação a objetos em PHP. Me deparei com o seguinte problema: tenho uma classe `Usuario` e preciso acessar o objeto assim que eu faço *login* no site, porém, quando tento acessar o objeto e a função de outras páginas, dá erro.

Como faço para acessar em outra página o objeto?

```
$Usuario->metodo();
```

temos a classe usuário  e logo a baixo

```
    <?php
 include_once("Conexao.php"); 
 class Usuario extends Conexao
 {  
    private  $id;
    private  $nome;
    private  $senha;
    private  $sessao;

    function setSessao($sessao){
        $this->sessao = $sessao;
     }...
```

a página gerente a qual eu instancio e a classe usuario e faço login

```
<?php
    $usuario = new Usuario();       

    $usuario->logar();
?>
```

a classe index a qual desejo usar o objeto instanciado na página gerente

```
<?php
     echo "<h1>".$usuario->getNome()."</h1>";
?>
```

o erro que aparece é esse :
Notice: Undefined variable: usuario in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\MyBiz\index.php on line 221

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNome() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\MyBiz\index.php:221 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\MyBiz\index.php on line 221
```

(obrigado pelas dicas)

Comment: Está chamando a classe na página que recebe os dados do login? Exemplo: `require_once('Usuario.php');`

Comment: @Hamilton, tem como explicar melhor o problema? Preferencialmente coloque todo o código que está utilizando referente a instanciação da classe e explique melhor o que seria este "outro arquivo".

Comment: você instanciou a classe? `$usuario = new usuario();` se não for isso, posta a mensagem de erro e o código abs – Diego Lela 5 mins atrás

Comment: Há `N` possibilidades. Tua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, sugiro que edite-a e acrescente informações como o código utilizado e principalmente o erro que está sendo exibido.

Comment: Então estou chamando sim a outra classe usuário pelo require_once. E também ja instanciei $usuario = new usuario;

Comment: Por favor, não publique seus códigos em forma de imagem. O site possui suporte para códigos, basta utilizar o botão `{ }` do editor.

Comment: @HamiltonVentura Amigo, poste qual erro está sendo gerado. Adendo: o objeto que você instanciou no Login não estará disponível em outras páginas, a não ser que você passe uma referência dele.

Comment: como posso passar por referÊncia? vi alguma coisa aqui sobre serialize com sessão, esse é o caminho ?

Comment: @HamiltonVentura Dê uma olhada em minha resposta. Utilizei uma forma mais fácil para você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma mais simples, você pode armazenar a instância criada do seu objeto `Usuario` numa sessão [(Documentação do PHP para funções de sessão)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.session.php) e acessar a mesmas na página desejada. Veja abaixo:

Enquanto na página `Gerente.php`

```
<?php
    $usuario = new Usuario();       

    $usuario->logar();
?>
```

Faça:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $usuario          = new Usuario();       
    $_SESSION['User'] = $usuario;

    $usuario->logar();
?>
```

Assim, na página `index.php`, você pode acessar a instância do seu objeto:

```
<?php
     echo "<h1>" . $_SESSION["User"]->getNome() . "</h1>";
?>
```

Ou ainda, na página `index.php`:

```
<?php
     $userObject = $_SESSION["User"];

     echo "<h1>" . $userObject->getNome() . "</h1>";
?>
```